# linear layout orientation changes

Tags: java, android, layout

What i want is :

- In portrait mode : an imageView and a text below
- In landscape mode : an imageView on the left and a text to the right

How can i do that ? knowing that in my manifest there is a :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in this activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an [alternative resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

```
res/layout-port/
```

(or `res/layout-land/`) where you define your additional layout. It will be used when you have the specified orientation, otherwise it will fall back to the default layout.

Comment: Okay, so i have to erase orientation in configChanges ?

Comment: If you do it that way, yes (see also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html))